# Replace image links in json file to base64 encoded data using webpack

Tags: json, image, webpack, base64

I have to create easily configurable website bundled into single file.
I'm using webpack 4.x

I have created json file with "configuration"

```
{
  "externals": [
    { "link": "http://lynda.com", "image": "./assets/lynda.jpg" },
    { "link": "https://www.mindtools.com/community", "image": "./assets/mindtools.jpg" },
    { "link": "https://www.ted.com/talks", "image": "./assets/ted.jpg" },
    { "link": "https://stackoverflow.com", "image": "./assets/stack.jpg" }
  ]
}
```

I have also configured base64-inline-loader in webpack

```
  // {
  //   test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png)(\?.*)?$/,
  //   use: 'base64-inline-loader?name=[name].[ext]'
  // },
  {
    test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'base64-inline-loader',
    options: {
      name: utils.assetsPath('[name].[ext]')
    }
  },
```

Both configurations above didn't work.
URLs created in vue component based on json data are still relative to file and of course those links points to 404 URLs.
All other inline images for CSS and HTML are processed correctly.

I'm doing something wrong, but i don't know what is this.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Done, but i'm not 100% happy with this resolution.

I have moved all data from json to application controller with require clause

```
data() {
    return {
      externals: [
        { link: "https://lynda.com", image: require('./assets/lynda.jpg') },
        { link: "https://www.mindtools.com/community", image: require('./assets/mindtools.jpg') },
        { link: "https://www.ted.com/talks", image: require('./assets/ted.jpg') },
        { link: "https://stackoverflow.com", image: require('./assets/stack.jpg') }
      ]
    };
}
```

on webpack site i'm using classic url-loader

```
test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
loader: 'url-loader',
options: {
    // limit: 10000,
    name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
}
```

still looking for normal json file processing possibility